# How do you display an image from s3 on a website?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to web development and to s3 and was wondering how I might be able to display an image thats inside my bucket, Im able to get a list of image and folder names inside the bucket but I want to find out how to display the images.  Would I need to provide a URL for my image tag in html?

Comment: What is exactly your question? How to create URL of the image in your bucket? Or how to display the image in a web page?

Comment: What would be best practice? My end goal is to display the images in my website, the only thing that comes into mind is using the URL but im not sure if there is a better way of achieving that.

Comment: To display an image in a web page you essentially have 2 possible ways:via **URL** and via **base64 encoded image**. The easisest way is by the URL if you can retrive the direct URL of the image from s3

Comment: Could you please ask your question a little bit more clear and provide some code snippet to let us understand your code better? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image stored in Amazon S3 can be included in a web page by using a normal `<img>` tag.

The URL to use is shown in the Amazon S3 console, but it would be something like:

```
http://BUCKETNAME.s3-REGION.amazonaws.com/folder/image.jpg
```

For example:

```
http://my-images.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/logos/foo.jpg
```

The object must be **publicly accessible**. This can be done in a few ways:

- The object itself can be marked as public
- A **Bucket Policy** on the bucket can designate the whole bucket, or a part of the bucket, as being public
- The URL can be augmented with an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides temporary access to a private object. This method is great for providing access to private images to a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of displaying images :

1) Base64

2) URL

Both ways are easy to integration using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

If you store an image in S3 you will need to give public access to it so can you can access this image .

After storing image to S3 it creates a URL which you can use in frontend to render that image .

Thank You